# how to deploy react js app on centOS 7 server using nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am very new in react app deployment and I want to deploy my react app on CentOS 7 server but I am not getting proper steps to deploy. Kindly help me to provide steps to deploy it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify the exact issue with minimal amount of code to reproduce it.

Comment: @TAM in nginx.conf file below code added.
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <Server IP>;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
        }

}